# How to compress uploaded image in django python

Tags: django, python-3.x, web, django-templates

have been going through many tutorials on python on how to compress images, Have used PILLOW but its not working. I will be grateful if I can get a full documentation on how to use PILLOW for image compression inside my django views.py

Comment: How did you try `PILLOW` and how did it fail? I mean, do you have some code and some stack trace of the error you faced maybe? It would be easier to solve the problem that way.

Comment: It's not working is not enough, you need to provide an example which doesn't work. 

Aside from that, you might want to use one of the existing libraries, like easy-thumbnails, sorl-thumbnail or something similar.

Comment: from PIL import Image              a = request.FILES['image']
        with Image.open(a) as image:
            image.thumbnail((400,400),Image.ANTIALIAS)
            b = image.save(output,format="JPEG")
            thumbnail_string = base64.b64encode(output.getvalue()).decode()
        product.image = thumbnail_string
        print(thumbnail_string)
        product.save()

Comment: The issue is that am trying to accept an image from the user and I want to compress/reduce the bytes before saving it in my database.

Answer (score 1):

i had used thumbnail() in pillow to compress images previously inside models.py The thumbnail() doesnt change the aspect ratio of image when resizing the image.

```
import sys

from django.db import models
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO
from django.core.files.uploadedfile import InMemoryUploadedFile

def compressImage(uploaded_image):
    image_temp = Image.open(uploaded_image)
    outputIoStream = BytesIO()
    image_temp.thumbnail( (1600,1600) )
    image_temp.save(outputIoStream , format='JPEG', quality=100)
    outputIoStream.seek(0)
    uploaded_image = InMemoryUploadedFile(outputIoStream,'ImageField', "%s.jpg" % uploaded_image.name.split('.')[0], 'image/jpeg', sys.getsizeof(outputIoStream), None)
    return uploaded_image

class ABC(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=/upload/path/here/, null=True, blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:
            self.image = compressImage(self.image)
        super(ABC, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```